# Can a WIN32 program authenticate into Django authentication system, using MYSQL?

Tags: python, windows, django, authentication, frameworks

I have a web service with Django Framework.
My friend's project is a WIN32 program and also a MS-sql server.

The Win32 program currently has a login system that talks to a MS-sql for authentication.

However, we would like to INTEGRATE this login system as one.

Please answer the 2 things:

1. I want scrap the MS-SQL to use only the Django authentication system on the linux server. Can the WIN32 client talk to Django using a Django API (login)?
2. If not, what is the best way of combining the authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either provide a view where your win32 client can post to the django server and get a response that means "good login" or "bad login". This will require you to modify the win32 client and create a very simple django view.

Or provide your own [Django Authentication backend](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#specifying-authentication-backends) that authenticates your django logins against the MS-sql server. This alternative will require no modification to your win32 client but probably quite a bit of effort on the authentication backend front. A bit of research might yield someone else's backend that you can re-use. [This looks like a promising place to start](http://www.mail-archive.com/django-updates@googlegroups.com/msg16966.html) - they claim that "Both Windows Authentication (Integrated Security) and SQL Server
    Authentication supported."

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing the WIN32 app uses the MS-SQL Server for is Authentication/Authorization then you could write a new Authentication/Authorization provider that uses a set of Web Services (that you would have to create) that expose the Django provider.

Comment: So, I have to MANUALLY talk to the MYSQL server, and manually manipulate the tables?

There's no API For this?